# How can Elasticsearch search characters like @

Tags: elasticsearch

I face the problem about writing Elasticsearch query.
My query is like below

```
{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "default_field": "content",
        "query": "@lin1"
    }
},
"from": 0,
"size": 1000,
"sort": [
    {
        "time": "desc"
    }
]
}
```

And I am using `query_string`
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html
But the `@` character can not match.
It will come out this kind of result: `lin1` or `「lin1」`

[image]

So how should I write the `Elasticsearch` query to match `@lin1`?

Comment: What text are you trying to match against?

Comment: I am searching `@lin1`

Comment: This I understood. In which text are you searching '@lin1'?

Comment: @Andrei Stefan string. Field is content

Comment: So, you have Chinese characters, as well. And '@' can be found inside words? What are the words separated by? Please, post the mapping.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/meteormatt/088bc982bd192ae19240

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the analyzer you are using. For all you know, you are using the standard analyzer which discards the '@' symbol from the index. In that case, you'll never be able to search for the '@' symbol. But if that is not the case and you do have '@' indexed, you can modify the `query_string` section of your query to below:

```
"query_string": {
    "default_field": "content",
    "query": "@lin1",
    "analyzer": "whitespace"
}
```

Comment: It search do not find anything. https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3844/15376849815_c9f7f20dc3_o.png

Comment: As I said, you might be using the default analyzer which does not index special characters like `@`. Can you paste the output of the command `GET <index name>/_mapping`? That will confirm my suspicion.

Comment: One thing to be careful with the whitespace: it does not lowercase terms https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html